# What is wrong with this xargs command?

Tags: xargs

I'm trying these two variations:

```
cat /var/log/zwave.log | xargs -n1 jq '.'
```

&:

```
</var/log/zwave.log xargs -n1 jq '.'
```

It seems for both the command runs but it tries to open the line as a file location. That makes sense for the second command I listed but for the first using a pipe shouldn't it act as if each line in `zwave.log` was piped to `jq '.'`?

---

*The logging system I'm processing but have no control over producing creates a json object on each line of the log file:*

```
{ "name": "PeriodicWork", "hostname": "myHost", "pid": 12189.20, "level": 20, "msg": "Executing [CheckFailedTask NodeId=8]", "time": "2017-12-04T00:20:30.953Z", "v": 0 }
```

*But the logger does occasionally fail and produce something like `Unable to start service: [TimeoutError: operation timed out]`.*

*That's why I can't just use `jq` on the file.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use xargs.

```
jq '.' /var/log/zwave.log
```

If you need to filter out only json lines, use grep in front of it

```
grep -E "^{" test.txt | jq '.'
```

Xargs is for appending each word¹ of its input as an argument to the given command; with `-n 1`, it is basically equivalent to running:

```
jq '.' "$word1"
jq '.' "$word2"
jq '.' "$word3"
```

which is what you are seeing. You should use xargs when the file contains a list of other files or arguments you want to pass to a command.

---

<sup>¹ words for `xargs` being whitespace delimited (at least space, tab and newline, YMMV depending on the locale and `xargs` implementation) but `xargs` also understands some form of quotings, though different from that of modern shells or of the JSON file format.</sup>

Comment: I want to use `jq` as a separate command on the contents of each line in the file.

Comment: jq acts on each line in a file/stream anyway. Or rather each json block.

Comment: jq won't act on each line if the content of the file can't be interpreted as a single json object

Comment: A full example of the input file would help

Comment: I added the expected format to the question, but as mentioned I already know I want to execute `jq` on each line of the file. I'm just trying to find the correct syntax for `xargs`.

Comment: Testing locally on your input jq does process each line in a file, you can use grep to filter out bad lines.

Comment: It does seem to work on the input I provided. Yet it doesn't work on the 6889 line log file I'm trying to process, and I can't post it as it as I'd have to read through every line for any potential confidential information :/

Comment: hmm I'm going to try the grep you posted now I didn't see that yet

Answer (score 0):

if your file actually is just line-after-line of json, this is trivial with jq

jq has built in support for this with `-s`

`cat my_file | grep -E "^{" test.txt | jq -sre '.'`

This will concat all the json into 1 array in jq, so you have to keep that in mind, but to give you an idea, you could do

`cat my_file | grep -E "^{" test.txt |jq -sre '.[].name'`

And this will dump all the names for you